# Spring Integration - reprocess messages from inbound file adapter by default after server restart

Tags: java, spring, file-io, spring-integration, messaging

I have a file inbound adapter wired to an file out bound gateway . Below is the configuration .

*

*

A bunch of files were processed as expected on one instance earlier in the day . Another instance was restarted for some reason ,a few hrs later and it started processing messages that were processed on another instance already .it resulted in a filenotfound exception for each message frm the outbound gateway

2015-02-19 00:46:15,761 [task-scheduler-8] INFO  org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler - Failed to move file '/tcserver/mounts/file_int/source/b31d688bc85c429bb4748f56a38f4e61'. Using copy and delete fallback.

2015-02-19 00:46:15,762 [task-scheduler-8] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - (inner bean)#8 received message: [Payload=org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: failed to write Message payload to file][Headers={timestamp=1424328375761, id=ad494ba5-795f-40d0-b523-74998088028e}]

2015-02-19 00:46:15,762 [task-scheduler-8] ERROR org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: failed to write Message payload to file
    at org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(FileWritingMessageHandler.java:293)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:134)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
.....

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tcserver/mounts/file_int/source/b31d688bc85c429bb4748f56a38f4e61 (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copy(FileCopyUtils.java:63)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler.handleFileMessage(FileWritingMessageHandler.java:352)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(FileWritingMessageHandler.java:277)

1)Does spring save the state of the system before a system shutdown in the server .
2) Any explanation on why this could happen could help greatly

Comment: <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn" directory="file:${files.source.directory}" prevent-duplicates="${prevent.file.duplicates}" filter="textFileFilter">
   
<int:poller trigger="filePollingTrigger" max-messages-per-poll="${file.polling.size}"/>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

Comment: <int-file:outbound-gateway id="filesOut" request-channel="filesIn" reply-channel="processFile"
        directory="file:${printexpert.files.processed.directory}" auto-create-directory="true" mode="REPLACE" delete-source-files="true" />

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple instances referencing the same source directory you need to use a persistent file list filter, together with a `MetadataStore` (e.g. Redis) to share state across the instances.

See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html).